# How can I use the "PowerShell Integrated Console" in VS Code?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I have the PowerShell extension installed under VSCode. When I open up a PowerShell script, VS Code automatically pops open a "PowerShell Integrated Console" window in my terminal. It's different from the normal PowerShell terminal:

[image]

It's better than the default one because keyboard shortcuts like Ctrl+Backspace to delete a word work. But when I try to open one of these fancy terminals myself, the option isn't there:

[image]

How can I get one of these improved terminals without opening a script file, and how can I get VSCode to use them automatically instead of the old PS terminal?

Comment: When you open a script file what does the powershell terminal say (anything about versions, etc?) What about when you manually open it in the terminal window?  My powershell that I can open manually in the terminal window has things like CTRL + Backspace working without issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note:

- Normally, a PIC (PowerShell Integrated Console) is automatically created *the first time you open a PowerShell source-code file for editing* in a session.
- The instruction below show to how to *directly* create a PIC, which may also be helpful if you need to *restart* it after a crash - though you're usually *prompted* to create a new one when that happens.

---

Instruction as of v2022.12.1 of the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) for VSCode (Visual Studio Code):

- Execute the `PowerShell: Show Session Menu` command from the command palette (<kbd>Ctrl-Shift-P</kbd>).

  - This will create a PIC *and* show a submenu, which you can simply dismiss with <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

    - Note: If the PowerShell extension was already loaded but the PIC has crashed, choose `Restart Current Session` from the submenu instead.
- Additionally, you may assign a keyboard shortcut to the command, by clicking the cog icon on the right edge of the command palette entry.

---

Because the PIC doesn't have an external executable entry point you can *not* define it as a custom shell profile (at least as of VSCode 1.67.1).

[GitHub issue #3918](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/3918) discusses implementing simpler ways to activate / load the PIC on demand as a future enhancement:

- Making the PIC show in the list of available shells (as shown in your question, analogous to the extension-contributed `JavaScript Debug Terminal` entry) is one of the suggestions, but the concern is that there can only be *one* PIC as of this writing, so such an entry would behave differently from other shells in the list, which create a *new* session every time.
- However, this concern would go away if support for *multiple* PICs were to be implemented, which is being proposed in [GitHub issue #2418](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/2418).